# How can I fix the SSL problem in Symfony/Goutte

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I'm trying to make a request to the website with Symfony/Goutte but I'm receiving such error:

```
In ErrorChunk.php line 65:
                                                                                                         
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for "https://example.com".  
                                                                                                         
In CurlResponse.php line 298:
                                                                                                         
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for "https://example.com".
```

Here's the code:

```php
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$client->request('GET', 'https://example.com');
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add HttpClient and disable SSL check... (do this only for debug) not in production!

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_host' => false]));
$client->request('GET', 'https://example.com');
```

Comment: But there's no `setClient` method in `Goutte\Client`

Comment: Changed to HttpClient for newer versions of Symfony.

Comment: If dependency injection is used, one can use `$this->client = $client->withOptions()`. https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#configuration

Answer (score 2):

If you work in localhost, you can disable SSL check globaly into config/packages/frameworks.yaml and paste this :

```
http_client:
    default_options:
        verify_host: false
        verify_peer: false
```

Hope that's help you !

Comment: Seems like it's `config/packages/framework.yaml` now. https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#configuration